# SSH server wont start before GUI login om Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: ssh, kubuntu

I have tried all the steps in  https://askubuntu.com/questions/3913/start-ssh-server-on-boot to no avail.

I want to be able to login via SSH on my tablet over the WiFi connection.  It works after being logged in at the physical machine but not before.  Otherwise it just comes up with connection refused.

Any ideas what to try next?

Comment: Its this any help? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1277/how-do-i-configure-wifi-to-log-in-to-wpa-at-boot-time-regardless-of-user-being

Comment: I don't know.  I had a look under Kubuntu  "system settings" and then under Network wireless connections and there was no option to start wireless network on startup or boot.

Comment: Turns out it was a wireless setting but it was a problem with gnome keyring

Answer (score 1):

Try

`systemctl enable sshd`

It should start the sshd on boot.

or try re-installing it:

```
sudo apt-get remove openssh-server --purge

sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

Than repeat `sudo systemctl enable sshd`

If the above doesn't work, try

`sudo systemctl enable ssh.service`

Also read: https://superuser.com/a/1069654

If it still doesn't work:

create a file called `rc.local` under the `etc` directory

The content of `rc.local`:

```sh
#!/bin/sh -e
sudo service network-manager start
sudo service ssh start
sudo service sshd start
```

Thén run `sudo systemctl enable rc-local.service`

Restart the system after editing.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work for me .  Here is what I got:

$ sudo systemctl enable sshd
Failed to enable unit: Refusing to operate on linked unit file sshd.service

Comment: Sorry about not being able to format my answer.  After only the second try it told me I wasn't allowed to edit it anymore.  Probably not enough reputation points.

Comment: Have you tried re-installing sshd

Comment: I have no idea how to do that reliably.  Although I do know how to run apt commands from the command line if that's what you are asking.  I am also on a slow internet connection which is probably going to cause me major headaches.

Comment: I put it in the answer. Give it a shot. If it doesn't work, we do it the rc.local way

Comment: Try the last method first before re-installing

Comment: Ok, I did all that.  I uninstalled and reinstalled openssh-server as per your comments.  I tried to SSH in from my android tablet but I kept getting "No Route to Host" errors until I logged in at the GUI on laptop running Kubuntu.  Once Kubuntu was logged in at the machine then the SSH app on the android told me that the keys had changed and asked me to accept the changes which I did and only then could I log in.  So unfortunately no change from before.

Comment: I should add that when I invoked the "systemctl enable ssh.service" I got several popups from kubuntu asking me to enter password and that happened several times.  However that didn't fix it.

Comment: do `sudo systemctl enable ssh.service`

Comment: $ sudo systemctl enable ssh.service
Synchronizing state of ssh.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable ssh
$ ^C

Comment: Seems good. Restart the system after it's done

Comment: I restarted it just now and it's still not working.  Still getting "No route to host" when I try to login from tablet using SSH until I log in at Kubuntu laptop.  'll try the rc.local way next

Comment: Next time when you're trying to connect pass in the `-vvv` argument and put the output in the question as well.

Comment: I tried the rc.local way.  I added in those commands as you typed it.  Still same problem.  Because I am using Juice SSH for android tablet I can't put in -vvv options but the error I get on tablet is "No route to host"

Comment: I'm using juicessh as well :)

Comment: I've already dont that.  That's the exact post I put in my opening paragraph.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't pay enough attention. But at least you know the reason right?

Comment: Try the new rc.local in the answer now. As long as we can start the network manager during  boots it should work.

Comment: Try the new flow for the rc.local

Comment: Ok I will run the rc defaults again.  I can't see what changes you have made to rc.local.  They look the same to me.

Comment: I add the command that will start network manager first. Also remember to run `sudo systemctl enable rc-local.service` after you have edited the file as rc.local is disabled by default

Comment: When I tried to run sudo systemctrl enable rc-local.service I got the following:

  The unit files have no installation config (WantedBy, RequiredBy, Also, Alias
  settings in the [Install] section, and DefaultInstance for template units).
  This means they are not meant to be enabled using systemctl.
  Possible reasons for having this kind of units are:
  1) A unit may be statically enabled by being symlinked from another unit's
     .wants/ or .requires/ directory.
  2) A unit's purpose may be to act as a helper for some other unit which has
     a requirement dependency on it.

Comment: 3) A unit may be started when needed via activation (socket, path, timer,
   D-Bus, udev, scripted systemctl call, ...).
4) In case of template units, the unit is meant to be enabled with some
   instance name specified.

Comment: At this point I really have no idea. I work with servers 99.9% of the time, and the worst case snario at least one of the above method will work. In your case try to get the rc.local to work because it interacts with the system during boot time  and might be more reliable.

Comment: Thanks for trying.  It may simply not be possible to achieve with Kubuntu 18.04

Comment: Almost everything is possible in Linux. Especially things as simple as starting something at boot :( I have a raspberry pi running Ubuntu mate with GUI. I can ssh into it without login.

Comment: It was a problem with gnome keyring and you have to save the internet password unencrypted for it to work. Apparently the gnome keyring doesn't start until GUI is logged in. They've closed the question so I can't highlight this as correct answer nor help anyone else with same problem